# Menu items not displaying in Navigation drawer view pager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have a navigation drawer with 2 fragments , fragment A and fragment B. Fragment B is a fragment with view pager and has fragment tab 1 and fragment tab 2. I am trying to display a search view in fragment tab1 and fragment tab 2 . I tried calling setHasOptionsMenu(true) in fragment tab 1 but onCreateOptions() is not called and hence searchview is never displayed. Can anyone please help how to get this to work? I have followed this tutorial : [View Pager+fragments+navdrawer](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-nested-viewpager-fragment-tabs-tutorial/)

Fragment 2 (holds the view pager)

```
public class TabsFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private PagerTitleStrip titleStrip;
private Menu menu;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_swipe, container, false);
    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),
            getSherlockActivity()));
    titleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.titlestrip);
    titleStrip.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    titleStrip.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E6000000"));
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    Log.d("tabs frag","on detach");
    super.onDetach();
    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class
                .getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Fragment tab 1 :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); 
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     Log.d(TAG, "on create options");  // never called
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchItem.setVisible(true);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
}
```

**UDPATE**

Tried the following code . Searchview in fragment tab 1 appears but now the adapter in tab1 shows null while executing onQueryTextchanged

```
if(adapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) instanceof FragTab1)
    {
        FragTab1 fragment = (FragTab1) adapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

        fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    searchAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText); // shows searchadapter is null eventhough I have filled it in onCreate.
    searched = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Any possible help would be greatly appreciated. Struggling on this for a whole day:(

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using Action Bar Compat instead of ActionBar Sherlock. Guess some issue with Sherlock library relating to child fragment or may be I missed something . But Action Bar Compat worked pretty fine without changing anything.